¿Por qué me devuelve el largo de la string?
Estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio.
Quiero que me cuente el numero de elementos dentro de una lista que previamente ha sido una String.
Pero me devuelve la longitud de la string.
frase = input('escribe frase')
lista_frase = list(frase)

print (len(lista_frase))

Lo cual me imprime:
escribe frase
esto es una prueba
18


Hola Jesús, bienvenido a [es.so]  ¿Que esperas obtener exactamente? ¿El numero de palabras? Seria bueno que agregaras la salida esperada para los ejemplos. list(str) convierte la cadena en una lista con los caracteres de la cadena, list("Hola") -> ['H', 'o', 'l', 'a']

Si frase es un string, es un iterable. Por lo tanto list(frase) será una lista de todos los elementos de frase. Es decir: una lista con todos los caracteres. Así está recogido en la documentación de list. Deberías probar: lista_frase = [frase].

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Python: Conversión de un string a tipo lista sin tener los caracteres separados

@JorgeLuis no se si realmente es una duplicada, ya que la pregunta carece de información para saber exactamente el objetivo del ejercicio.

Buenas muchas gracias.
Finalmente lo he resuelto de esta manera.
Dejo ejercicio completo.
print ('CONTADOR DE PALABRAS') print ('\n') frase = input('Escribe una frase') lista_frase = frase.split() print (f"Tu frase tiene: {len(lista_frase)} palabras")
Escribe una frase
Esto es una prueba
Tu frase tiene: 4 palabras

Te devuelve la cantidad de caracteres, ya que en realidad estás imprimiendo el número de elementos en la lista  ( ['e', 's', 't', 'o', ' ', 'e', 's', ' ', 'u', 'n', 'a', ' ', 'p', 'r', 'u', 'e', 'b', 'a']
) que se crea a partir de la cadena que ingresas:
lista_frase = list(frase)
print (len(lista_frase))

Te sugiero usar split() para crear una lista de las palabras de la cadena ingresada y posteriormente usar len() para obtener la cantidad de palabras en la lista:
frase = input('escribe frase: ')
#lista_frase = list(frase)
lista_frase = frase.split()
print(lista_frase)
print(len(lista_frase))

salida:
['esto', 'es', 'una', 'prueba']
4

